# Vscode Plugin CompletionItemProvider Trigger failure to vue

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am developing a plug-in for the vscode style completion prompter. In the HTML file, the completion prompt can be triggered normally, but in the vue file, it is not triggered. I suspect that it may not be a code problem, because I have asked Chat GPT many times and it still has not been resolved

1. HTML [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru4Ib.png)
2. VUU [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0jBO.png)
3. My Plugin Code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL3Xg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZKVq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN2yo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJlL8.png)

I would like an answer if the code is causing this issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyOn2.png) why??

Comment: why post images of text, why do you have a `pattern` for vue files and your file does not match with the file pattern

Comment: where in the VSC API doc do they mention that `package.json` has a `completionItemProvider` entry in the `contribute`

Comment: In the vue file, the completion prompt cannot be triggered

Comment: you don't answer the reason for the `pattern` property

Comment: CompletionItemKind. Property? The icon that indicates the supplementary full information changes.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the code as text instead of images. Also, for the screenshot, please add meaningful titles. It's quite hard to read and understand the question.

Comment: enter in the html file class="t" trigger but in vue file class="t" does not trigger

Comment: Find hints in the documentation of tailwindcss, you need to enable the option to "on" in the "editor.quickSuggestions" setting of VScode